# How do I modify my program to allow the user to specify the integer step between values

Tags: java

I have to create a program that generates random values and allows the user to specify the starting value and the ending value, both integers which is I got. However, when I have to modify the program to let the user decide the step pattern I am lost and don't know what to do. How do I get the outcome I am looking for?

I have done research but the pyramid of number is not the outcome I am looking for.

```
import java.util.Random;

class RandomNumberGenerator {
    public static int rand(int min, int max) {
        if (min > max || (max - min + 1 > Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range");
        }
        return new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Pick the min range:");
        int min = In.getInt();
        System.out.println("Pick the range. From " + min + " to ");
        int max = In.getInt();\\
        let the user choose their step pattern
        System.out.println("what would you like the step pattern to be?");
        int pattern = In.getInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            System.out.println(rand(min, max));
    }
}
```

I want the results to look like: -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5 when the min is -5 and the max is 5 with the user's inputted step pattern of 2 (it is ok if the order is at random) .

Comment: Why are you generating the numbers randomly if they are completely determined by user input?

Comment: What does step mean here? What about what you described needs to be random? It all seems very deterministic from your write up. Do you want to select randomly from an increasing range? Like the first number is randomly chose from the set `[-5, -4]`, the second from `[-3, -2]`, third from `[-1, 0]` and so on?

Comment: For my assignment, I had to first create a program that allows the user to determine the min and max and output numbers from the range randomly. The the second part is to create a integer step between values, and I am not sure if I need to take out the random or keep it. As it does not matter if the number are in random order as long as it outputs information in the specified step value.

Comment: By step value I mean, from the range provided by the user for example, 0 - 11 the user can input the value the number should increase by. For example, range: 0-11 step value is 2, output: 2,4,6,8,10

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand your problem, I think this is your solution for both parts

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Stepping {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputter = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter min value: ");
    int min = inputter.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter max value: ");
    int max = inputter.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How many random numbers to generate: ");
    int range = inputter.nextInt();
    // part 1
    generateUniqueRandoms(min, max, range);
    // part 2 stepping
    System.out.print("Enter stepping/interval between min and max: ");
    int stepping = inputter.nextInt();
    stepping(min, max, stepping);
  }

  private static void generateUniqueRandoms(int min, int max, int range) {
    // assuming you have taken care of validation
    Set<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>();
    while (uniques.size() != range) {
      uniques.add((int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
    }
    System.out.println(uniques);
  }

  private static void stepping(int min, int max, int stepping) {
    // take of validation yourself
    int next = min;
    List<Integer> allSteps = new ArrayList<>();
    allSteps.add(min);
    while (next < max) {
      next += stepping;
      if (next < max) {
        allSteps.add(next);
      }
    }
    allSteps.add(max);
    System.out.println(allSteps);
  }
}
```